# QString replace characters outside of quotes

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently reading in a json file to a QJsonDocument and then converting it to a QString such that it looks like:

```
"thing1":"thing1value",

"thing2":"thing2,value",

"thing3":"thing3value",
```

Each line ends with a comma and I would like to try and format it a bit to show to the user without the quotations and a new line after each line. I was attempting use the replace function to replace any commas with a new line. The problem is that just using the replace function to replace all commas with \n also means that anything inside the quotes is altered too like:

```
"thing2":"thing2

value"
```

Is there any easy way to alter the values exterior of quotes without touching the insides? Is there perhaps a better approach to the overall formatting I could be doing instead? I have a feeling this is asking a bit much of Qt and I may just have to write some function that indexOf finds the first quote and tracks it to the next etc.

Here's what I have so far essentially

```
    QString jDoc = file.readAll();
    file.close();

    QJsonParseError parserError;
    QJsonDocument jsonInit = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jDoc.toUtf8(), &parserError);
    qDebug() << parserError.errorString();
    QString strJson(jsonInit.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented));
```

Comment: The first and very important step is to show the relevant piece of code, which someone could modify to do what you want.

Comment: I mean currently there is no code I just have a QJsonDocument I've converted to a string but that's not really helpful to the question

Comment: _I just have a QJsonDocument I've converted_ did you do that manually on paper?

Comment: I mean I can supply the code that I used to read the json file to a QJsonDocument but I don't feel like that's really helpful to answering my question

Comment: It will be helpful, because then we are going to be on the same page. It is not a good idea to force the others to start from scratch, or to guess what you have done for that matter.

Comment: Edited to inclulde hopefully what you were looking for

Comment: You can do that with a QRegularExpression, something like \"[a-Z0-9]\"\: etc, look into the Qt docs.

Comment: Which line gives you the `"thing1":"thing1value",...` output? Also is there a comma between each `thing` and `value`?

Comment: No the idea is that each line ends with a comma but occasionally inside the quotations will be a comma also. Just displaying that strJson in my Qt application with ui->textBrowser->setText(newText);

Comment: Why not just iterate through `jsonInit` and print the keys and values how you like rather than converting it to a string then trying to format it afterwards?

Comment: @Ashherz, please add these details to your question.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

Use [QString::right](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#right) to retrieve the value and then [QString::arg](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg) to format the output to your liking.

## Example

Here is a minimal example I have prepared for you of how to implement this solution:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QJsonObject json {
        {"thing1", "thing1value1"},
        {"thing2", "thing2,value2"},
        {"thing3", "thing3value3"}
    };

    QString newText;

    foreach (const QString &key, json.keys()) {
        const QJsonValue &value(json.value(key));
        const QString &str(value.toString().mid(key.length()));

        newText.append(QString("\"%1\":\"%1\n\%2\"").arg(key).arg(str.startsWith(",") ? str.mid(1) : str));

        if (key != json.keys().last())
            newText.append("\n\n");
    }

    auto *textBrowser = new QTextBrowser(this);

    textBrowser->setText(newText);

    setCentralWidget(textBrowser);
}
```

## Result

The example produces the following result:

[image: Window with the processed JSON]

## Credit

Special thanks for the valuable help of correcting the bug in the code to **Some Programmer Dude** (@Someprogrammerdude):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52402760/5366641

Comment: But does it work with the initial example? What if you remove the comma in an item's value?

Comment: @FrederikDeRuyck, it is fixed now.