# Why a comma is omitted at the beginning of a string using QString::right?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

Answering [QString replace characters outside of quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52399753/5366641) I have stumbled upon a strange behavior.

Executing this code:

```
foreach (const QString &key, json.keys()) {
    const QJsonValue &value(json.value(key));

    qDebug() << key << value.toString().right(key.length());
}
```

with this `json`, *A*:

```
QJsonObject json {
    {"thing1", "thing1value1"},
    {"thing2", "thing2value2"},
    {"thing3", "thing3value3"}
};
```

and with this `json`, *B* (notice the comma after `thing2`):

```
QJsonObject json {
    {"thing1", "thing1value1"},
    {"thing2", "thing2,value2"},
    {"thing3", "thing3value3"}
};
```

in both cases produces:

```
"thing1" "value1"
"thing2" "value2"
"thing3" "value3"
```

Should not be:

```
"thing1" "value1"
"thing2" ",value2"
"thing3" "value3"
```

in the second case, *B*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`QString::right`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#right) function

> Returns a substring that contains the ***`n` rightmost*** characters of the string.

<sub>[Extra emphasis mine]</sub>

Since the length of the key string is `6`, then the `6` rightmost characters will be returned, giving you `"value2"` without the comma.

If you want to get the string without the leading key you could use [`mid`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#mid) instead:

```
value.toString().mid(key.length())
```

For your use-case I would rather suggest [`midRef`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#midRef), since there's no need to actually create a *copy* of the sub-string.

Comment: For a moment I was confused where the counting starts and the coincidence fooled me that it works. It is the wrong function to use. Thank you for putting me back on track!